# Does $ \mbox{rank} (A B) \leq \min \left( \mbox{rank} (A), \mbox{rank}(B) \right)$ hold with probability $1$ when matrices $A$ and $B$ are random?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, matrix-rank, random-matrices

For two non-random matrices $A$ of size $n\times p$ and $B$ of size $p \times m$ we know that

$$ \mbox{rank} (A B) \leq \min \left( \mbox{rank} (A), \mbox{rank}(B) \right)$$

One can construct examples where there is a strict inequality (such as $A = (1,0), B=(0,1)^T$) but how likely are these to occur if every entry of matrices $A$ and $B$ is sampled independently from a zero-mean Gaussian distribution with finite variance?

To me, it seems that if the entries are random, then intuitively we should have that equality holds with probability $1$, i.e.,

$$ \mbox{rank} (A B) = \min \left( \mbox{rank} (A), \mbox{rank}(B) \right)$$

but I cannot find any proof of this. Does anyone have a proof of this or some reference to where I can read more about this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

First, we can observe that with probability $1$, $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \min\{n,p\}$ and $\operatorname{rank}(B) = \min\{p,m\}$. This holds not just for independent Gaussian entries, but in a very general case.

To prove this, suppose that we generate the rows of $A$ one at a time. At any given step, if the previous rows do not yet form a basis of $\mathbb R^p$, then their span is at most a hyperplane in $\mathbb R^p$, and the probability that the next row is in that hyperplane has probability $0$. So if $n \le p$, then the rows of $A$ are linearly independent with probability $1$; the other facts needed to prove that the rank is what we want are similar.

So we want to show that with probability $1$, $\operatorname{rank}(AB) = \min\{n,p,m\}$. This goes similarly to the above proof.

The columns of $AB$ are $A\mathbf b^{(1)}, \dots, A \mathbf b^{(m)}$ where $\mathbf b^{(1)}, \dots, \mathbf b^{(m)}$ are the columns of $B$. We'll show that if these are generated one at a time, then up until they span the column space of $A$, they'll remain linearly independent. The idea is the same: the set of vectors $\mathbf x$ such that $A\mathbf x$ is in the span of $A\mathbf b^{(1)}, \dots, A \mathbf b^{(i)}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^p$. If $A\mathbf b^{(1)}, \dots, A \mathbf b^{(i)}$ do not yet span the entire column space of $A$, then the set is not all of $\mathbb R^p$, so it's a proper subspace. Therefore a random $\mathbf x$ lies in it with probability $0$; in particular, the probability that $A \mathbf b^{(i+1)}$ lands in the span of $A\mathbf b^{(1)}, \dots, A \mathbf b^{(i)}$ has probability $0$.

So the columns of $AB$ are either linearly independent or span the column space of $A$. In the first case, $\operatorname{rank}(AB) = m$; in the second case, $\operatorname{rank}(AB) = \operatorname{rank}(A) = \min\{n,p\}$. So we conclude that $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \ge \min\{n,p,m\}$, and since this is also an upper bound, we get what we wanted.

Comment: Thank you for the clear proof!

Comment: @Misha Lavrov In the last paragraph - why is it an upper bound?

Comment: @Undertherainbow because $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \le \min\{\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(B)\}$, $\operatorname{rank}(A)\le\min\{n,p\}$, and $\operatorname{rank}(B)\le\min\{p,m\}$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Sorry, I meant where did the lower bound rank(AB)≥min{n,p,m} come from?

Comment: That's... the what the whole answer was about. If the rank is either $m$ or at least $\min\{n,p\}$, then it's always at least $\min\{m,n,p\}$.